# How should I present a Modal VIew Controller from TabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have an app whose initial scene is a tab bar controller with 3 tabs.  I created a `uitabbarcontroller` class and set it to that scene (`MainTabViewController`).

In that class I call presentLogin from the `viewDidAppear` method and that method reads:

```
- (void)presentLogin{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (![prefs stringForKey:@"storedUser"] && ![prefs stringForKey:@"storedPass"]) {
        NSLog(@"No user prefs stored");

        // BUT WAIT, before all this, lets pop up a view controller for user registration
        UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
        ModalViewController *popupController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ModalViewController"];
        [self presentViewController:popupController animated:YES completion:nil];

    } else {
        NSString *storedUser = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"User:%@",[prefs stringForKey:@"storedUser"]];
        NSString *storedPass = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"User:%@",[prefs stringForKey:@"storedPass"]];
        UIAlertView *internetAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:storedUser
                                                                message:storedPass
                                                               delegate:self
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [internetAlert show];

    }
}
```

But the `modalVC` isnt showing for some reason.  I get this crash log:

```
Attempting to begin a modal transition from <MainTabViewController: 0xa55d0d0> to <ModalViewController: 0x15e2b5e0> while a transition is already in progress. Wait for viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear to know the current transition has completed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you get this error because the tab bar controller is putting the view of the controller in its first tab on screen at the same time you're presenting the modal controller. Instead of presenting it from the tab bar controller, present it in the viewDidAppear method of the controller in the first tab. Call it with no animation to see the modal view controller without seeing the firs tab controller.

Comment: It was the ANIMATION:NO that fixed the issue!  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a tiny delay like below:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self performSelector:@selector(presentLogin) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The view of the tabbarcontroller contains the viewHierarchies of the viewControllers that the tab bar itself owns. Maybe something is of because of that. Try to see of you still get the error if you only have one viewcontroller set to the tabbar.